# Trouble smoothing a curve

Tags: bevel

Issue that I'm having is that I'm trying to round off / bevel smooth the hard edges on this object. Have been watching some videos and reading on different smoothing and beveling techniques but not having any success so far.

What I'm trying to get is a similar profile to what you would find on most eye glasses legs where the edges are smoothed out so as not to bug the wearer.

[image]

I can kind of bevel the straight edges of the object ok with the boolean tool or modifier, but they keep getting hung up on that section I cut out.

Here's an example using the boolean modifier:
[image]

Here's an example of using subdivision:

[image]

If I use the bevel tool in edit mode, the edges get a little smoothing but not to any great effect:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to apply your scale (CTRL-A) With your scales that wild the bevel modifier will give bad results. You've definitely got something weird with the curved part. Maybe it is not connected properly? Have you done Merge by Distance of all verts?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/